# How to set input file in command in HTM Software for Multiview Video

Tags: hevc, multiview, h.265

I'm new in HM Software. I've tried HM Software for Mono and Stereo Video, and now i little bit confusing using HTM Software for Multiview Video. I use config file `baseCfg_3view.cfg` for video Balloons that I downloaded from [here](http://3d-codec.multimedia.edu.pl/). In config file `baseCfg_3view.cfg` there are example setting for input video :

```
#======== File I/O =====================
InputFile_0                   : newspapercc_4.yuv                              
InputFile_1                   : newspapercc_2.yuv                               
InputFile_2                   : newspapercc_6.yuv
```

So i try using same command as Mono and Stereo for Multiview to encode the video:

```
./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/MV-HEVC/baseCfg_3view.cfg  -i ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_synth_tex_cam02.75_cam03.25_QP29.yuv -o out.yuv -q 36 -b ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_common_bin_QP29_base.bin -wdt 1024 -hgt 768 -fr 30 | tee out.log
```

And i got this error :

```
Error parsing option "Frame1" with argument "B    8     1    0  0     0.442    0        0        0        4      4     -8 -10 -12 -16     0      0".

3D-HTM Software: Encoder Version [16.2] based on HM Version [16.9][Linux][GCC 4.8.5][64 bit]
```

I don't know how to set input file video in command to encode the video, Should I using correspond video instead using video from the link above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

In I/O configuration :

`#======== File I/O =====================`

`InputFile_0                   : newspapercc_4.yuv`
`InputFile_1                   : newspapercc_2.yuv`
`InputFile_2                   : newspapercc_6.yuv`

Just make sure the path of your input file, on this case my input video file path located in folder /testseq/, so change the InputFile_0,InputFile_1, and InputFile_2 become :

`InputFile_0                   : ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_synth_tex_cam02.75_cam03.25_QP29.yuv.yuv`
`InputFile_1                   : ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_synth_tex_cam02.75_cam03.25_QP29.yuv.yuv`
`InputFile_2                   : ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_synth_tex_cam02.75_cam03.25_QP29.yuv.yuv`

and then i run again the command

`./TAppEncoderStatic -c ../cfg/MV-HEVC/baseCfg_3view.cfg -q 36 -b ../testseq/balloons_00_1024x768_common_bin_QP29_base.bin -wdt 1024 -hgt 768 -fr 30 | tee out.log`

It works for me